# How to get full Wikipedia revision-history list from some article?

Tags: python, web-scraping, wikipedia-api, revision-history

How can I get the full Wikipedia revision-history list? (Don't want to scrape)

```
import wapiti
import pdb
import pylab as plt  
client = wapiti.WapitiClient('mahmoudrhashemi@gmail.com')
get_revs = client.get_page_revision_infos( 'Coffee', 1000000)
print len(gen_revs)

500
```

Package link: https://github.com/mahmoud/wapiti

Comment: Isn't `get_revs` the full revision list? What's missing?

Comment: @Kevin It isn't. It is merely 500.

Comment: @Morgan Thrapp https://github.com/mahmoud/wapiti . I am open to any package/code that does the job.

Comment: Take a look at the [MediaWiki API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Revisions) the API will only let you get 500 revisions.

Comment: @Morgan Thrapp Thanks for the info! Any workarounds? Is scraping allowed?

Comment: Nope. Generally if the API won't let you do it, it's because you're not supposed to do it.

Comment: @Morgan Thrapp any iterative calls with timestamp increments etc?

Comment: I have no idea. I've never used the API. Why not try it?

Answer (score 9):

If you need more than 500 revision entries you will have to use [MediaWiki API](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Brevisions) with action **query**, property **revisions** and parameter **rvcontinue**, which is taken from the previous request, so you can't get the whole list only with one request:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=Coffee&rvcontinue=...
```

To get more specific information of your choice you'll have to use also **rvprop** parameter:

```
&rvprop=ids|flags|timestamp|user|userid|size|sha1|contentmodel|comment|parsedcomment|content|tags|parsetree|flagged
```

Summary of all available parameters you can find [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Revisions).

This is how to get the full Wikipedia's page revision history in C#:

```
private static List<XElement> GetRevisions(string pageTitle)
{
    var url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=xml&prop=revisions&rvlimit=500&titles=" + pageTitle;
    var revisions = new List<XElement>();
    var next = string.Empty;
    while (true)
    {
        using (var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)WebRequest.Create(url + next).GetResponse())
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var xElement = XElement.Parse(reader.ReadToEnd());
                revisions.AddRange(xElement.Descendants("rev"));

                var cont = xElement.Element("continue");
                if (cont == null) break;

                next = "&rvcontinue=" + cont.Attribute("rvcontinue").Value;
            }
        }
    }

    return revisions;
}
```

Currently for *"Coffee"* this returns **10 414** revisions.

---

**Edit:** Here is a Python version:

```
import urllib2
import re

def GetRevisions(pageTitle):
    url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=xml&prop=revisions&rvlimit=500&titles=" + pageTitle
    revisions = []                                        #list of all accumulated revisions
    next = ''                                             #information for the next request
    while True:
        response = urllib2.urlopen(url + next).read()     #web request
        revisions += re.findall('<rev [^>]*>', response)  #adds all revisions from the current request to the list

        cont = re.search('<continue rvcontinue="([^"]+)"', response)
        if not cont:                                      #break the loop if 'continue' element missing
            break

        next = "&rvcontinue=" + cont.group(1)             #gets the revision Id from which to start the next request

    return revisions;
```

How you see the logic is absolutely the same. The difference with C# is that in C# I parsed the XML response and here I use regex to match the all `rev` and `continue` elements from it.

So, the idea is that I make a [main request](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=xml&prop=revisions&rvlimit=500&titles=Coffee) from which I get all revisions (the maximum is 500) into `revisions` array. Also I check the `continue` xml element to know are there more revisions, get the value of the `rvcontinue` property and use it in `next` variable (for this example from the first request it is `20150127211200|644458070`) to make [another request](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=xml&prop=revisions&rvlimit=500&titles=Coffee&rvcontinue=20150127211200%7C644458070) to take the next 500 revisions. I repeat all this until the `continue` element is available. If it missing, this means that no more revisions after the last one in the response's revision list are left, so I exit from the loop.

```
revisions = GetRevisions("Coffee")

print(len(revisions))
#10418
```

Here are the last 10 revisions for *"Coffee"* article (they are returned from the API in reversed order), and don't forget that if you need more specific revision information you can use `rvprop` parameter in your request.

```
for i in revisions[0:10]:
    print(i)

#<rev revid="698019402" parentid="698018324" user="Termininja" timestamp="2016-01-03T13:51:27Z" comment="short link" />
#<rev revid="698018324" parentid="697691358" user="AXRL" timestamp="2016-01-03T13:39:14Z" comment="/* See also */" />
#<rev revid="697691358" parentid="697690475" user="Zekenyan" timestamp="2016-01-01T05:31:33Z" comment="first coffee trade" />
#<rev revid="697690475" parentid="697272803" user="Zekenyan" timestamp="2016-01-01T05:18:11Z" comment="since country of origin is not first sighting of someone drinking coffee I have removed the origin section completely" />
#<rev revid="697272803" parentid="697272470" minor="" user="Materialscientist" timestamp="2015-12-29T11:13:18Z" comment="Reverted edits by [[Special:Contribs/Media3dd|Media3dd]] ([[User talk:Media3dd|talk]]) to last version by Materialscientist" />
#<rev revid="697272470" parentid="697270507" user="Media3dd" timestamp="2015-12-29T11:09:14Z" comment="/* External links */" />
#<rev revid="697270507" parentid="697270388" minor="" user="Materialscientist" timestamp="2015-12-29T10:45:46Z" comment="Reverted edits by [[Special:Contribs/89.197.43.130|89.197.43.130]] ([[User talk:89.197.43.130|talk]]) to last version by Mahdijiba" />
#<rev revid="697270388" parentid="697265765" user="89.197.43.130" anon="" timestamp="2015-12-29T10:44:02Z" comment="/* See also */" />
#<rev revid="697265765" parentid="697175433" user="Mahdijiba" timestamp="2015-12-29T09:45:03Z" comment="" />
#<rev revid="697175433" parentid="697167005" user="EvergreenFir" timestamp="2015-12-28T19:51:25Z" comment="Reverted 1 pending edit by [[Special:Contributions/2.24.63.78|2.24.63.78]] to revision 696892548 by Zefr: [[WP:CENTURY]]" />
```

Answer (score 7):

If you use pywikibot you can pull a generator that will run through the full revision history for you.  For example, to get a generator that will step through all the revisions (including their content) for the page "pagename" in English Wikipedia, use:

```
site = pywikibot.Site("en", "wikipedia")
page = pywikibot.Page(site, "pagename")
revs = page.revisions(content=True)
```

There are a lot more parameters you can apply to the query. You can find the API documentation [here](https://doc.wikimedia.org/pywikibot/master/api_ref/pywikibot.html#pywikibot.Page)

Of note is:

> revisions(reverse=False, total=None, content=False, rollback=False, starttime=None, endtime=None)

Generator which loads the version history as Revision instances.

pywikibot appears to be the approach taken by many Wikipedia editors to automate editing.

Comment: For anyone struggling what to do with `revs` at this point like I did, you can convert it to a list `list(revs)`.

Comment: That certainly works if the list is small enough to load into memory.  Mine aren't :)  Instead I loop: for rev in revs: