# how to get wikipedia revision edits fastest

Tags: python, wikipedia

I want to get the number of wikipedia revision edits for many entities. For example, the number of deletion or addition.

e.g.
link:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Help%3APage_history&type=revision&diff=%22+696846306+%22&oldid=%22+688747750

[difference between two revisions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKg7J.png)
But each entity has much revisions from earlier time(e.g.2006) to now. Around 10000 revision ids for one entities. So if I retrieve difference pages one by one. It would be very slow! Is there some more efficient way to do this task?

Comment: Have you looked at the wikipedia api?

Comment: You could fetch a [Wikimedia database dump](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/) and do all the processing offline.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get full Wikipedia revision-history list from some article?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34411896/how-to-get-full-wikipedia-revision-history-list-from-some-article)

Comment: @pvg I already had a look. But no finding

Comment: @ephemient good idea! I will have a look when I go home.

Comment: @downshift hi, Wikipedia revision history I already got. But it's not the final result I want. I need to compare old revision page and new revision page and compare how many deletions or additions they made. I can get this result but it's very very slow. If I make it faster, I think Wikipedia doesn't want me to do that also.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [API for getting edits on Wikipedia](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40313820/api-for-getting-edits-on-wikipedia)

Comment: I searched a own way to make it faster a little bit more. Thanks